# Generic Linq query NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to filter some results in Entity Framework core generically through a helper class but I'm getting this error and I don't know why:

`NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable'1[eVendCustomerDAL.DomainModels.Bin]).Any(__funcTest_0)': The given arguments did not match the expected arguments: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.`

And this is where the error is happening:

```
    public virtual Revision<DTO> GetStateAsRevision(
        Expression<Func<Domain, bool>> query) {
        //get all the stateful data from the database
        DbSet<Domain> oriSet = db.Set<Domain>();
        //query all the data
        List<Domain> oriList = oriSet.Where(query).ToList();
```

The error seems to occur because of the `query` parameter that I'm pushing through and it only occurs as runtime. I'm not sure if the fact it's generic is to blame. The generics are classes and not interfaces also.

```
where DTO : BaseRevisionDTO
where Domain : BaseTrackedObject
where DomainRevision : BaseRevision
```

I then build the expression using the following snippets:

```
    private Expression<Func<Domain, bool>> GetDomainSearchExpression(Func<Domain, bool> shortFunction) {
        DbSet<Domain> modelTable = CustomerContext.Set<Domain>();

        Expression<Func<Domain, bool>> expr =
        d =>
        modelTable.Any(shortFunction);

        return expr;
    }

    protected override Func<DomainModels.Bin, bool> GetDomainSearchFunction() {
        return x => x.Station.Machine.UniqueId == MachineID;
    }
```

**Edit 1:**

So if I call the above code like so:

```
        GetStateAsRevision(GetDomainSearchExpression(GetDomainSearchFunction()));
```

It will error at:

```
        List<Domain> oriList = oriSet.Where(query).ToList();
```

And this is the entire stack trace:

```
NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[eVendCustomerDAL.DomainModels.Bin]).Any(__shortFunction_0)': The given arguments did not match the expected arguments: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.MethodCallExpressionParser.CreateExpressionNode(Type nodeType, MethodCallExpressionParseInfo parseInfo, Object[] additionalConstructorParameters)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.MethodCallExpressionParser.Parse(string associatedIdentifier, IExpressionNode source, IEnumerable<Expression> arguments, MethodCallExpression expressionToParse)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.ExpressionTreeParser.ParseMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression, string associatedIdentifier)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.ExpressionTreeParser.ParseTree(Expression expressionTree)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.GetParsedQuery(Expression expressionTreeRoot)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionVisitors.SubQueryFindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionVisitors.SubQueryFindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListPartitionIterator.ToArray()
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.MethodCallExpressionParser.Parse(string associatedIdentifier, IExpressionNode source, IEnumerable<Expression> arguments, MethodCallExpression expressionToParse)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.ExpressionTreeParser.ParseMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression, string associatedIdentifier)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.ExpressionTreeParser.ParseTree(Expression expressionTree)
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.GetParsedQuery(Expression expressionTreeRoot)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore<TResult>(Expression query, INodeTypeProvider nodeTypeProvider, IDatabase database, ILogger logger, Type contextType)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<CompileQuery>b__0()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore<TFunc>(object cacheKey, Func<Func<QueryContext, TFunc>> compiler)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute<TResult>(Expression query)
Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase.GetEnumerator()
System.Collections.Generic.List..ctor(IEnumerable<T> collection)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
eVendWebAPI.Helpers.DALHelpers.GetRevisionHelper.GetStateAsRevision(Expression<Func<DomainModel, bool>> query) in GetRevisionHelper.cs
+
            List<DomainModel> oriList = oriSet.Where(query).ToList();
eVendWebAPI.Helpers.DALHelpers.GetRevisionHelper.GetRevision(Expression<Func<DomainModel, bool>> query) in GetRevisionHelper.cs
+
            return GetStateAsRevision(query);
eVendWebAPI.Areas.Customer.Controllers.Base.BaseAPIRevisionController.Get() in BaseAPIRevisionController.cs
+
            return Ok(helper.GetRevision(searchExpr));
lambda_method(Closure , object , Object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware+<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Your `shortFunction` is a `Func<>` and not an `Expression` so it can't be converted to SQL. Try making it's type `Expression<Func<>>` instead.

Comment: Hey thanks man! What's that all about then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `shortFunction` is a `Func<>` and not an `Expression` so it can't be converted to SQL. Try making it's type `Expression<Func<>>` instead.

The C# compiler has special logic to convert a lambda into two types - if the desired result type is `Func<>` then it converts it to compiled code and if the result type is `Expression` it converts it to an `Expression` tree that represents the code (a cheat added for LINQ). A data provider can read that expression tree and emit code for the database in question (such as SQL) but it can't decompile the compiled IL code back into something it can output in another language.